# Good method for finding roots that *usually* fall within an interval?

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, roots, computational-mathematics

I've been using Brent's method to find the roots of a monotonic, nonlinear, non-differentiable function.  The roots often fall within a known interval, but Brent's method fails if they occasionally don't.

What's a good method of solving for roots that starts looking within a known bracket, but can expand the bracket if needed?

Comment: In case of a failure, double the interval and try again. But your function most probably deserves better than a black-box approach.

Comment: As Yves suggested, you can probably do better than a black-box method. What is the function? How is it computed? In what context does it arise?

Comment: The function would take a paper to describe, but it has to do with the error in a function calculated via a numerical ODE solution. It's monotonically increasing and relatively smooth.